# pip install deepspeed ERROR: error: subprocess-exited-with-error/error: metadata-generation-failed

Tags: python, deep-learning, triton, deepspeed

When I try to install the **deepspeed** library in the **conda** virtual environment, the following error occurs

```py
Collecting deepspeed
  Using cached deepspeed-0.12.6.tar.gz (1.2 MB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × python setup.py egg_info did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [14 lines of output]
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "<string>", line 2, in <module>
        File "<pip-setuptools-caller>", line 34, in <module>
        File "C:\Users\v-yuztian\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-rfwu18pc\deepspeed_742daeca15db4a0a8412e86c8378a2e5\setup.py", line 182, in <module>
          abort(f"Unable to pre-compile {op_name}")
        File "C:\Users\v-yuztian\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-rfwu18pc\deepspeed_742daeca15db4a0a8412e86c8378a2e5\setup.py", line 52, in abort
          assert False, msg
      AssertionError: Unable to pre-compile async_io
      [WARNING] Torch did not find cuda available, if cross-compiling or running with cpu only you can ignore this message. Adding compute capability for Pascal, Volta, and Turing (compute capabilities 6.0, 6.1, 6.2)
      DS_BUILD_OPS=1
       [WARNING]  async_io requires the dev libaio .so object and headers but these were not found.
       [WARNING]  If libaio is already installed (perhaps from source), try setting the CFLAGS and LDFLAGS environment variables to where it can be found.
       [WARNING]  One can disable async_io with DS_BUILD_AIO=0
       [ERROR]  Unable to pre-compile async_io
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: metadata-generation-failed

× Encountered error while generating package metadata.
╰─> See above for output.

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for details.
```

My installation environment is as follows:
OS:Windows11
python:3.10

I tried upgrading pip wheel and setuptools but it didn't work. I tried installing triton==1.0.0 again but it says this installer does not exist, maybe it only supports linux environments!

Comment: Update Python 3.12.1